# Failed to install pod: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

According to [AdMob documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/facebook), in order to integrate with facebook audience network I need to install this pod:

```
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

When I try to install it, I received an error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADUnifiedNativeAdView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FacebookAdapter(GADFBNativeAd.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Unfortunately I didn't find a solution for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode may not be inheriting the linker flags from the Pod project. Inside your Build Settings, if you search Other Linker Flags do you have `$(inherited)` listed?

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It worked after I deleted an old version of FBAudienceNetwork.framework's path in Framework Search Paths.

Comment: That is my answer, it is how I solved the problem specifically.

Comment: Hi, how please?