# Audiokit Audiobus Integration with Errors like: :-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPort

Tags: swift, audiokit, audiobus

i have implemented audiobus/iaa in my app like in this tutorial:
https://audiokit.io/audiobus/sender-synth/
i have received my api key from audiobus and copied it in a textfile called "Audiobus.txt". but i am still getting these errors:

> undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPort",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudiobusController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioSenderPort", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioFilterPort", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Audiobus.o   "_ABConnectionsChangedNotification", referenced from:
>         exprDrumSlide.Audiobus.(startObservingAudiobusConnections in _9FD53C91DFE572A59DC04EC281AF80F7)() -> () in Audiobus.o
>         exprDrumSlide.Audiobus.(stopObservingAudiobusConnections in _9FD53C91DFE572A59DC04EC281AF80F7)() -> () in Audiobus.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> :-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABPort :-1: Undefined symbol:
>   _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudiobusController :-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioSenderPort :-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABAudioFilterPort :-1: Undefined symbol: _ABConnectionsChangedNotification

---

updating to calalina and the latest xcode/audiokit version helped. i can build the project now but the app is crashing with this error:

2020-04-08 13:35:50.361550+0200 supaSynthApp[13692:2137570] Temporary Audiobus API Key: 12 days remaining
2020-04-08 13:35:50.424671+0200 supaSynthApp[13692:2137570] CFSocketSetAddress listen failure: 102
2020-04-08 13:35:50.424797+0200 supaSynthApp[13692:2137570] CFSocketSetAddress listen failure: 102
2020-04-08 13:35:50.438629+0200 supaSynthApp[13692:2137570] Your app icon could not be found by Audiobus. Please make sure your app has an icon and that it's correctly registered in Info.plist (CFBundleIcons, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Try adding "$(inherited)" to the build settings in your target under "Other Linker Flags".

I tried this after reading this post: [Failed to install pod: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106219/failed-to-install-pod-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64?rq=1)

"Xcode may not be inheriting the linker flags from the Pod project. Inside your Build Settings, if you search Other Linker Flags do you have $(inherited) listed?"

Answer (score 0):

i finally made the app work.. just added AppIcons:
[image]